# Change Custom List Close Button

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-foundation

I have a Custom List called "Items" When a user Views or Edits an item in this list I would like the Close or Save button to redirect the user to the home page and not the Default "All Items" of the list.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

Using the below code you can achieve this. It allows to set the redirection on the client-side

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var button = $("input[id$=SaveItem]");
    // change redirection behavior
        button.removeAttr("onclick");
        button.click(function() {
            var elementName = $(this).attr("name");
            var aspForm = $("form[name=aspnetForm]");
            var oldPostbackUrl = aspForm.get(0).action;
            var currentSourceValue = GetUrlKeyValue("Source", true, oldPostbackUrl);
            var newPostbackUrl = oldPostbackUrl.replace(currentSourceValue, "MyRedirectionDestination.aspx");

            if (!PreSaveItem()) return false;
            WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(elementName, "", true, "", newPostbackUrl, false, true));
        });

});
```

Source : [Link](https://adrianhenke.wordpress.com/2010/08/19/custom-redirect-after-creating-a-new-sharepoint-item/)

Comment: Forgive me for the newbie question. How or where do I add this code to my page to use this code?

Comment: Simply SPD 2013 or else use Script editor web part on the page do you want to do this functionality.

Comment: ok so I added a Script Editor to my New Item page, but nothing happens when I save the item, it still returns to the default all items view

Comment: Give your custom redirect home page Url in `newPostbackUrl`

Answer (score 0):

Using below mentioned trick you can change the button's redirection behavior in Display or Edit form.

[Change SharePoint List “Display Item Form” Close Button Default Redirect Location](https://hpksanje.wordpress.com/2014/06/28/change-sharepoint-list-display-item-form-close-button-default-redirect-location/)

I hope it works for you.

Thanks.

Comment: Is this solution works as per your need?

Comment: Hello man is that works for you? did you achieved it?